# How to automatically sync files in github desktop?

Tags: github, github-desktop

My partner and I are working on a website and the file folder is being shared between us via github. We need a way of automatically syncing the changes that either of us make to the files on either of our computers so we can both edit the site live.

How can I set it up so that changes made to the repository are automatically synced with files on our computer? Without one of us having to go hit the sync button every time?

Comment: Is there a special reason for using git in this case? To me this sounds like you should be using some online IDE or something from which you (both) can edit the files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to accomplish the auto sync. But remember git will refuse to sync in case of conflict. You will have to manually pull the changes and resolve conflict.

Comment: How exactly would we do this? Also we have tried port forwarding- what would be the best way to make it so that we can both edit a website hosted on one person's servers? So we can BOTH edit the site live?